# Elementary os Hera only booting into tty

Tags: greeter

I hadn't updated my laptop in about 3 months, I usually just suspend it.

I finally restart it and i'm only able to boot into tty.

I know reinstalling the os would fix the issue, but I have 1TB worth of data that i'd rather not loose.

**What i've tried so far**

1. Reinstalling elementary-desktop
2. Reinstalling lightdm
3. Reinstalling Xorg
4. Trying to start light service using systemctl which fails
5. Trying to start Xorg using startx which also fails

Please I would appreciate any help or ideas in resolving this issue.

Comment: Are there any messages in `/var/log/syslog` or in `/var/log/boot.log.X` that point to why the system is stopping at TTY?

Comment: I was able to fix by deleting my `xorg.conf` file in `etc/X11/xorg.conf` it now shows a gui login screen, but not the default elementary login screen